# Submitting a PHP form with onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I currently have a download link and an input field for an email address on my website.

In order to download the file you first need to put in your email.

I use a form to do this, with the email field being an input field and the download button being a submit button.

I like HTML5's form validation (the required fields, field types etc, it all looks very nice).

The problem is that if I use onClick in my submit button then none of the nice form validation works.

```
<form>
     <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Please enter email" required>

     <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="downloadWin()" value="Windows">
     <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="downloadOsx()" value="Osx">  
</form>


<script>
    function downloadWin(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if(email != ''){
            if(validateEmail(email)){
                location.href='http://s/index.php?page=downloadWin&email='+email;
            }
        }
    }

    function downloadOsx(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if(email != ''){
            if(validateEmail(email)){
                location.href='http://s/index.php?page=downloadOsx&email='+email;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

This might not be the cleanest way to do it, so please if you think you know a better way tell me :)

Comment: change the type of download into radio button and use one submit input. Change onclick into onSubmit function in jQuery. If you need more explanation ping back... I'll explan you further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<form onsubmit="download(this.email.value,this.system.value)" id="form">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter email" required>
    <input type="radio" name="system" value="Win" required >Windows
    <input type="radio" name="system" value="Osx" >Osx
    <input type="submit" class="btn"  value="Download"> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

function download(email_value,sys_value){
    location.href='http://s/index.php?page=download'+sys_value+'&email='+email_value;
}
</script>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: event hasn't been defined. This will throw error. Besides this validation is provided by HTML5 and will for non-HTML5 browsers.

Comment: @Samundra 1.The questioner want to use html5 to validate, So I just give a simple example that only use html5 without js. 2.I did not see error in console without define event, and as you say, I add event now, is it more robust now?

Comment: Oh I somehow missed that. (y)

Comment: Great! It's all working beautifully now. Not often you get a live and tested example answer, and even with a gif!! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
function downloadWin() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (email != '') {
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            location.href = 'http://s/index.php?page=downloadWin&email=' + email;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function downloadOsx() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (email != '') {
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            location.href = 'http://s/index.php?page=downloadOsx&email=' + email;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the working code snippet (without using HTML5 validation). You can run and test it. I have used the `jquery` with `jquery.validate` plugin. You can uncomment the commented code to redirect user to the target url. Let us know if this what you are looking for or not. Feel free to comment if there is anything that you feel confusing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-download").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       if ($("#validateForm").valid()) {
            var name  = $(this).val();
            var email = $("#email").val();

            if (name === "Windows") {
                //location.href = 'http://s/index.php?page=downloadWin&email=' + email;
                console.log('http://s/index.php?page=downloadWin&email=' + email);
            }

            if (name === "Osx") {
                console.log('http://s/index.php?page=downloadOsx&email=' + email);
                //location.href = 'http://s/index.php?page=downloadOsx&email=' + email;
            }
        }            

    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="validateForm" novalidate>
     <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Please enter email" required>
     <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-download" value="Windows">
     <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-download" value="Osx">  
</form>
```